# How can I loop through the each div tag with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have this piece of code that loops through the divs when I hit enter.

```
<input type="text" id="keywords"></input>

document.getElementById("keywords").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("mark");
    
        for (var y=0; y<element.length; y++) {
            console.log(y);
        }
        }
        
    }, false);
```

But the console logs something like: 0 1 2 3 4...
I'd like it to log each new index every time I hit enter. So it would be like: 0 (enter) 1 (enter) 2 (enter) 3...
How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need `document.getElementsByTagName` at all?

Comment: @Unmitigated I am doing the search like ctrl+f and I'm trying to figure out how to do the enter functionality with this. If user types something in the input and the keyword matches to some word on the page, the word on the page gets wrapped into the custom html tag "mark". This Is how I detect how many matched keywords are there on the page in this case. (When I ask a question everyone get really confused by the "mark" tag I thought it would be easier if I change it to "div" but I guess it is confusing too, so I just leave it as "mark". It doesnt matter anyway, my question is about the loop.)

Comment: Can't you just add the value to an array, or does the "mark" element have a special purpose? Are you highlighting things. setting some CSS? @Maroun

Answer (score 0):

You could create a handler function that sets up an `index` variable, and caches the `div`s, that then returns a new function (called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) that is called whenever the event happens.

```js
function handler() {

  // Create the index and divs variable.
  // These variables will be carried into the closure
  let index = 0;
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

  // Because the closure maintains references
  // to the variables in its "outer lexical environment"
  // you can update them when it's returned from the handler
  return function () {

    // Now just check to see if the index value is
    // less than the length of the collection of elements
    // If it is log the value, and increase the index
    if (index < divs.length) {
      console.log(index);
      index++;
    } else {
      console.log('Nothing to log');
    }
  }
}

const keywords = document.querySelector('#keywords')

// Call the handler function so that the the variables
// can be initiated, and the closure that the listener will be
// using can be returned
keywords.addEventListener('keyup', handler(), false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keywords"></input>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: I edited the question and added the comment explaining what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let keyword = document.getElementById('keywords');
  var enterCount = 0;
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
  keyword.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      if (enterCount < divs.length) {
        console.log(enterCount);
        enterCount += 1;
      }
    }
  })

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keywords"></input>
<span>123</span>
<span>345</span>
<span>567</span>
```

I think you are looking for something like this. You can change the span tag into your div. This span tag just for an example purpose.

Comment: So I changed the for loop to an if statement like in your code but it just logs zeros every time I hit enter so it doesnt actually loops through the tags

Comment: how about the variable count to save the number of counts. Did you add that part as well @Maroun?